# Side lobe level of an aperture antenna

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, physics, radiation, far-field

There is a electric field in the far zone of the rectangular aperture antenna as shown below.

Antenna lies along the xy plane.
$$E_{\theta}=\dfrac{jke^{-jkr}}{4\pi r}\dfrac{sin(0.5\lambda k sin\theta sin\phi)}{ksin\theta sin\phi}$$
$$E_{\phi}=\dfrac{jke^{-jkr}}{4\pi r} cos\theta \dfrac{cosh(\lambda k sin\theta cos\phi)-1}{\lambda k^2 sin^2\theta }$$

How can I find the first side lobe level of this kind of complicated pattern?

Comment: How about plotting it as graphs in excel to get a feel for it.

Comment: I edited the question